# Unable to access jarfile in a tmux session from startup

Tags: server, cron, minecraft, tmux, jar

I have a script which starts a new tmux session and runs the Minecraft launch command like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a new session and run a command inside the session
tmux new-session -d -s mc
tmux set-option -t mc set-remain-on-exit on
tmux send-keys -t mc "java -Xmx6G -jar fabric-server-mc.1.19.4-loader.0.14.19-launcher.0.11.2.jar nogui" Enter
```

I'm able to run a similar script manually and it launches just fine, I'm able to see the Minecraft server run and access it's CLI from there. I say "similar script" but it just lacks the `set-remain-on-exit on` (needed to run tmux from crontab) and attaches the session, it has nothing to do with the issue.

While I've used crontab to launch this script at startup and tmux does work, all that shows up after attaching the session is:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile fabric-server-mc.1.19.4-loader.0.14.19-launcher.0.11.2.jar
```

I've tried `chmod +x`, `chmod 755`, and `chmod 777` for the script, but no such luck. I'm not sure why the jarfile cannot be accessed when launched from crontab, would anyone know why?

Edit: Attempting to specify the entire java path (`/usr/bin/java`) also doesn't help.

I've found that when loading it from anywhere outside the directory it's in, the jarfile will be inaccessible, naturally this also affects cron, so how would I fix this, at least for cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, I needed to add the directory in the launch script to specify the where the jarfile is, despite the launch script being in the same place.

```
#!/bin/bash

#set the working directory
cd /home/minecraft/fabric-1.19.4

# Create a new session and run a command inside the session
tmux new-session -d -s mc
tmux set-option -t mc set-remain-on-exit on
tmux send-keys -t mc "java -Xmx6G -jar fabric-server-mc.1.19.4-loader.0.14.19-launcher.0.11.2.jar nogui" Enter
```